# redirect www and nonwww to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web

htaccess code to redirect all requests for example.com to sub.example.com

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://sub.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It's working only when I ask http://example.com (non www version) but when I go to www.example.com it's not redirecting.

Basically I prefer a clean method to redirect all requests from example.com (www and NON www) to sub.example.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://sub.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```